# Django, Nginx, Gunicorn. Ubuntu 16.04 error

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

i'n trying to run server with this - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04#create-a-gunicorn-systemd-service-file

When i try to run some commands, i get this error - **sudo: unable to resolve host giver.local**

what can be the problem?

Comment: That's far too vague. *What* command did you run, exactly?

Comment: for example sudo systemctl start gunicorn

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates something is wrong in your `/etc/hosts` or `etc/hostname`

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-when-i-run-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-none.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `/etc/hosts` file for this line:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
```

Assuming it’s printing the error correctly, `giver.local` is in place of `localhost`.

If this doesn’t work, I’d recommend deleting that droplet and starting anew as this error isn’t common (as far as I or Google knows).